# Getting error while creating adonis js new project

Tags: javascript, node.js, adonis.js

The below error occurring while creating new adonis js application

[image]

my node and npm versions are

[image]

What is reason of this error? thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- If you are trying to install a adonis 3.2 you need the `adonis-cli`
- If you are trying to install a adonis 4.0 or greater you need `@adonisjs/cli`